# mysql workbench forward engineer error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Dears,

I have created a database model and was hopeping to script it to MySQL smoothly using Workbench.

below is the code generated by the WB:

```
    -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema resume_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema resume_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `resume_db` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `resume_db`.`vacancies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`vacancies` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `htmlDesc` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `issueDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `expiryDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `resume_db`.`job_history`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`job_history` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `employerName` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `employement_duration` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `job_title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `duties` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `applications_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `applications_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `resume_db`.`education_record`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`education_record` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `school_name` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `degree_period` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `degree_title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `degree_notes` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `applications_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `applications_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `resume_db`.`social_networks`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`social_networks` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `social_network` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `profile_url` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `applications_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `applications_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `resume_db`.`applications`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`applications` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `name` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  `photo_url` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `videoUrl` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `vacancyID` INT NULL,
  `location` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `skills` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `htmlCoverLetter` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `resume_url` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_applications_vacancies_idx` (`vacancyID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_applications_vacancies`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vacancyID`)
    REFERENCES `resume_db`.`vacancies` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_applications_job_history1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `resume_db`.`job_history` (`applications_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_applications_education_record1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `resume_db`.`education_record` (`applications_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_applications_social_networks1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `resume_db`.`social_networks` (`applications_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

unfortunately once executed i get the following error msg:

```
    Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `employerName` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `employe' at line 5
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `resume_db`.`job_history`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`job_history` (
          `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
          `employerName` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
          `employement_duration` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `job_title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          `duties` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
          `applications_id` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `applications_id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

from the MY SQL Manual... I think you need an expression.

Generated column definitions have this syntax:

```
col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
  [VIRTUAL | STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]
  [[NOT] NULL] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
```

AS (expression) indicates that the column is generated and defines the expression used to compute column values. AS may be preceded by GENERATED ALWAYS to make the generated nature of the column more explicit. Constructs that are permitted or prohibited in the expression are discussed later.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_db`.`job_history` (
         `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `employerName` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
          `employement_duration` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `job_title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          `duties` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
          `applications_id` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `applications_id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Otherwise , why generate a virtual id column?